# incomplete read error returned in sqlite in pandas notebook

Tags: python, sqlite, http, pandas

I am connecting to a website, I have created two tables to store the data and I am trying to collect the data after a certain date, and I am returned an error. I dont know if I need to add code to my handler section, but my code for collecting the data is shown below:

```
record_cnt = 0  
for link in data_list_post:
    data = pd.read_table(link, sep=',')
    print('%s:%s rows %s columns' % (link[-10:-4],data.shape[0], data.shape[1])) 
    record_cnt += data.shape[0]
    data.to_sql(name='post', con=conPost, flavor='sqlite', if_exists='append')
```

and the error I am returned is:

```
IncompleteRead: IncompleteRead(8437886 bytes read)
```

Full error traceback:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\http\client.py in _get_chunk_left(self)
    540             try:
--> 541                 chunk_left = self._read_next_chunk_size()
    542             except ValueError:

C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\http\client.py in _read_next_chunk_size(self)
    507         try:
--> 508             return int(line, 16)
    509         except ValueError:

ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 16: b'00004000\r00:00,REGULAR,0000262144,0000327687                                                  \n'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

IncompleteRead                            Traceback (most recent call last)
C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\http\client.py in _readall_chunked(self)
    557             while True:
--> 558                 chunk_left = self._get_chunk_left()
    559                 if chunk_left is None:

C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\http\client.py in _get_chunk_left(self)
    542             except ValueError:
--> 543                 raise IncompleteRead(b'')
    544             if chunk_left == 0:

IncompleteRead: IncompleteRead(0 bytes read)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

IncompleteRead                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-13-e9dcb24183ff> in <module>()
      1 record_cnt = 0
      2 for link in data_list_post:
----> 3     data = pd.read_table(link, sep=',')
      4     print('%s:%s rows %s columns' % (link[-10:-4],data.shape[0], data.shape[1])) #printing out values makes me feel safe....
      5     record_cnt += data.shape[0]

C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in parser_f(filepath_or_buffer, sep, delimiter, header, names, index_col, usecols, squeeze, prefix, mangle_dupe_cols, dtype, engine, converters, true_values, false_values, skipinitialspace, skiprows, skipfooter, nrows, na_values, keep_default_na, na_filter, verbose, skip_blank_lines, parse_dates, infer_datetime_format, keep_date_col, date_parser, dayfirst, iterator, chunksize, compression, thousands, decimal, lineterminator, quotechar, quoting, escapechar, comment, encoding, dialect, tupleize_cols, error_bad_lines, warn_bad_lines, skip_footer, doublequote, delim_whitespace, as_recarray, compact_ints, use_unsigned, low_memory, buffer_lines, memory_map, float_precision)
    560                     skip_blank_lines=skip_blank_lines)
    561 
--> 562         return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
    563 
    564     parser_f.__name__ = name

C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
    299     filepath_or_buffer, _, compression = get_filepath_or_buffer(
    300         filepath_or_buffer, encoding,
--> 301         compression=kwds.get('compression', None))
    302     kwds['compression'] = (inferred_compression if compression == 'infer'
    303                            else compression)

C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\common.py in get_filepath_or_buffer(filepath_or_buffer, encoding, compression)
    315         # cat on the compression to the tuple returned by the function
    316         to_return = (list(maybe_read_encoded_stream(req, encoding,
--> 317                                                     compression)) +
    318                      [compression])
    319         return tuple(to_return)

C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\common.py in maybe_read_encoded_stream(reader, encoding, compression)
    235             reader = BytesIO(reader.read())
    236         else:
--> 237             reader = StringIO(reader.read().decode(encoding, errors))
    238     else:
    239         if compression == 'gzip':

C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\http\client.py in read(self, amt)
    453 
    454             if self.chunked:
--> 455                 return self._readall_chunked()
    456 
    457             if self.length is None:

C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\http\client.py in _readall_chunked(self)
    563             return b''.join(value)
    564         except IncompleteRead:
--> 565             raise IncompleteRead(b''.join(value))
    566 
    567     def _readinto_chunked(self, b):

IncompleteRead: IncompleteRead(8437886 bytes read)
```

Comment: Does it happen every time?

Comment: It has happened with this notebook, I dont know if you have any suggestions this is the first time I am doing this.

Comment: What I mean is, if you try and run it lots of times, does it always fail?

Comment: three  times this has happened

Comment: Can you provide the full error traceback?

Comment: I provided it in the main question @ChuckM

Comment: what is `data_list_post`? Is it a list of urls?

Comment: data_list_post is a data schema for after 10/18/14 @ChuckM

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143619/discussion-between-chuckm-and-kwashington122).

Comment: Can you run `print link` under your for loop and tell me what the result is?